# ES6 - Wrapping console.log() with substitutions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a custom logger that adds extra formatting when outputting to console.

```
class Logger {

    Log(moduleId, message, ...args) {
        var d = new Date(),
            h = (d.getHours()<10?'0':'') + d.getHours(),
            m = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes(),
            s = (d.getSeconds()<10?'0':'') + d.getSeconds();
        var timestamp = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

        console.log('[%s | %s] - %s', timestamp, moduleId, message, ...args);
    }

}

var instance = new Logger();
module.exports = instance;
```

It would then be called like so:

```
Logger.Log('Web', 'Request %s completed in %dms MS', url, new Date() - benchmark);
```

The expected result would be

```
[20:03:30 | Web] - Request http://example.com completed in 193dms MS
```

However, instead what outputs is

```
[20:03:30 | Web] - Request %s completed in %dms MS http://example.com 193
```

It seems that my current implementation breaks `console.log()`'s token substitution mechanism. Why is this happening and how can I get around it?

Comment: You can't do `Logger.Log()` with what you've declared.  `Log()` is an instance method, not a static method.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated my post to include its use of Node module caching

Comment: The tokens specified in the string in console.log's first arg get substituted with the values of it's subsequent args. But your log implementation places a format string in console.log's 4th arg, so I wouldn't expect that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use substitution in the `string` that is substituting a token. The best you could do is to use `string` concatenation to construct the first argument you pass to `console.log`.

Here is an example.

```js
class Logger {
    static Log(moduleId, message, ...args) {
        var d = new Date(),
            h = (d.getHours()<10?'0':'') + d.getHours(),
            m = (d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes(),
            s = (d.getSeconds()<10?'0':'') + d.getSeconds();
        var timestamp = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

        console.log('[%s | %s] - ' + message, timestamp, moduleId, ...args);
    }
}
Logger.Log('Web', 'Request %s completed in %dms MS', "https://....", 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your string `console.log('[%s | %s] - %s', timestamp, moduleId, message, ...args);` with

```
console.log(`[${timestamp} | ${moduleId}] - ${message}`, ...args);
```